# Heptathlon point system calculation

Tags: rules, olympics, scoring, heptathlon

Are there equations that are used to calculate the scores (as in diving and such)?

If so, what are these equations?

And if not, please state how the points are calculated.

Answer (score 5):

> The scoring system was developed by Dr. Karl Ulbrich. The events are split into three parts, where the scores are counted according to the three formulae:
>
> Running events (200 m, 800 m and 100 m hurdles):
>
> [image: Running formulae]
>
> Jumping events (high jump and long jump):
>
> [image: Jumping formulae]
>
> Throwing events (shot put and javelin):
>
> [image: Throwing formulae]
>
> P is for points, T is for time in seconds, M is for height/length in centimeters and D is length in meters. a, b and c have different values for each of the events (see table).
>
> [image: Values per event]

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heptathlon).

The point are given for every event and sum up to the heptathlete score (A competitor in a heptathlon is referred to as a heptathlete).

Comment: Please note that the men's events have different a,b,c values.

Comment: @Ste Mens are competing in Decathlon.

Comment: At the Olympics yes, but not in Indoor Athletics.

Comment: To add to this: in competition, these scores are not calculated, but rather assigned from a table which is calculated from these formulas.