# Derivation of variables in the heptathlon point system equations

Tags: olympics, scoring, heptathlon

The point system equations for the heptathlon are listed at the following question - [Heptathlon point system calculation](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/heptathlon-point-system-calculation)

My question is how did the founders of this scoring system come up with the numbers for a,b and c?

Comment: I would assume some kind of fit to make them equally important

Comment: I heard on TV yesterday, that it is linked to the world record

Comment: You should start a bounty on this one. Pretty interesting. I could not find the answer haha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [iaaf document](http://www.iaaf.org/mm/Document/Competitions/TechnicalArea/ScoringTables_CE_744.pdf) about the scoring tables they just state the basic rules which they tried to meet with the system from 1983 (p.18):

> 1. The new set of tables should be used for combined events only.
> 2. Results in various events should, as far as possible, yield about the same number of points if the results are comparable as to quality
>      and difficulty.
> 3. The new tables should be either:
>
>    - a modification of the existing ones
>    - **a straight line in all events**
>    - slightly progressive tables in all events.
> 4. It must be possible to use the scoring tables for beginners, juniors and top athletes as well.
> 5. There will be a special scoring table for men and another table for women.
> 6. **All the new versions of the scoring tables should be based on the statistical data for the combined events by paying due regard to the
>      statistical data for performances by single event athletes.**
> 7. The new tables should be applicable now and for the future.
> 8. **It is desirable without creating other problems, that the total scores using the new tables for the top world class athletes should
>      remain approximately the same. That is about 8500 points for the
>      decathlon and about 6500 points for the heptathlon.**
> 9. **As far as possible the new tables must insure that a specialist in one event cannot overcome performances in the other events.**

It also says that it was created in a meeting with "several statisticians".

[Wikipedia says for Decathlon scoring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decathlon_scoring_tables#1934_scoring_tables) (which it seems uses the same factors) the 1934 scoring system was based on exponential functions fitted for 0 Points based on the results of untrained children to 1000 Points closely to the world records with a limit at 1150 Points per event.

Since all newer systems seem to have evolved from this one I guess the procedure was the same with changes to the functions used (throwing events changed from progressive to regressive) and the data used for fitting.

That was all I could find so no data or statistics but if you google you find several papers by statistician that propose different scoring methods to replace the old one.